# Exchange Online Emails into Event Hubs

Tags: office365, azure-eventhub

Does anyone know if/when we'll start to be able to stream Exchange Online emails into Event Hubs?

I'm currently working through Graph to gather emails, but due to API limits this isn't ideal.

It would be great to be able to get all emails into Event Hubs, similar to compliance centre but with less delay and more data from the emails.

For my comment below, here's what you seen when querying the API at https://api.securitycenter.windows.com/api/advancedqueries/run.

[EmailEvents API Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzbqj.png)

And then here's the success when running the queries directly from within Advanced Hunting at https://security.microsoft.com/advanced-hunting.

[EmailEvents Advanced Hunting Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3zIi.png)

Comment: I saw that MDATP has schemas with email data, and I can get results through https://security.microsoft.com/advanced-hunting.  But when I try to run similar queries through https://security.microsoft.com/interoperability/api-explorer for things like EmailEvents, I get an error about the table not being available.

Comment: Hi welcome :). Add in those details to the body of your question proper, and keep trying while we wait for someone that knows to chime in

Comment: I've added the API bits in here, as it looks like those emulate the options available within https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/raw-data-export-event-hub?view=o365-worldwide.  The only bits of the schema that appear to work are under the Devices heading.

Comment: Ah, thanks, but do copy the text of the errors into here as well, so they can be found when someone searches for them